# How to cancel one specific SKAction.movebyX in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have an `SKAction` that I want to cancel in `touchesEnded`. As of right now, I have this code: `self.player.removeAllActions()` and the code works. The problem that I'm experiencing is that the code is cancelling all actions including animation of my player. I did research and found a code: `player.removeActionForKey()`, but my action code does not include for key. Please see my code below to help. Thank you.

```
import SpriteKit

var player = SKSpriteNode()

//i skipped code in view did load. 
// now in touches began:

let rightMoveAction = SKAction.moveByX(50, y: 0, duration: 0.1)
player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(rightMoveAction))

let leftMoveAction = SKAction.moveByX(-50, y: 0, duration: 0.1)
player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(leftMoveAction))

// in touches ended

self.player.removeAllActions()

// as i mentioned earlier, it works but i need to cancel 1 action not all as i have an animated player.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign an action a key, and then cancel it by referring to the key:

Add the key to the action:

```
player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(rightMoveAction), withKey: "RightMove")
```

And then remove it by doing this:

```
player.removeActionForKey("RightMove")
```